# How to restrict insertion of value that already exists in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables. I need to check before insertion in one table if the value exist in other table.

Comment: Do you need to restrict the insertion for a single operation, or for *any* insertion operation?

Comment: For any insertion operation on the selected table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that, you should first check the records that is going to be inserted in each request.

```
Create Proc Testing
as
Set NoCount ON
Set XACT_ABORT ON

Begin Try
   Begin Tran
    IF Not Exists(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 i JOIN Table1 t ON i.key = t.key)
    Begin
         //Your insert statement
    END
   Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
    Rollback Tran
End Catch
```

Comment: This does not answer the question exactly. This checks to see if the value exists in BOTH tables. The question was how to check to see if it is in `Table1` before inserting into `Table2`. Your code will allow the insertion if the value exists in `Table1` only.

Answer (score 1):

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Col1 = @Value)
INSERT INTO TableB(Col1) SELECT @Value

Comment: I think, mentioning column names instead of star is better.

Comment: I've seen an article few years ago about it that starting with SQL 2005, optimizer treats *, 1 or the column name the same if it's inside of EXISTS statement. I compared them several times and execution plans are exact.

Answer (score -1):

Using an [INSERT trigger](http://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+insert+trigger) perhaps?

I'm not very sure about the syntax.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTableTrigger ON Table1 FOR INSERT
 AS
  BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Inserted i JOIN Table1 t ON i.key = t.key )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Transaction Failed.',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN "insert on Table1"
    END
  END
 GO
```

Inserted is used to access the inserting values.

Comment: How do I use inserting value?

Comment: Suppose I insert a batch of 100 records. out of 100, it already contains 40 records in other table and 60 are new one. as per the the above statement, it should rollback the complete batch!!

Comment: @SQL: That may or may not be a problem. Depends entirely on the actual requirements. If 100 rows contain values that are related to each other, denying all the batch might seem more reasonable than denying only part of it. Anyway, you've made a good point.

Comment: I am sure that in this context, the whole batch will be rollback. after taking care of the OP requirements.

Comment: @Whoever-downvoted: could you please let me know why? If there is a mistake, I'd like to correct it.